# Why can I not Alt-Tab to TWINUI in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

When I open a PDF in Windows 8 it is opened in TWINUI, which I presume is a Windows 8 App. When I Alt-Tab away from it I can not Alt-Tab back to it, it is gone from the list of applications shown when holding down Alt and pressing Tab.

Since I have not found anyone else with this problem when searching for it, I guess I have made some change to my system, but I can not recall what, in that case.

**How can I make Apps (*TWINUI in particular*) appear in the list of windows when Alt-Tabbing?**

Answer (score 0):

TWINUI is a Windows bug where it's trying to open an application using built-in Windows app but the application or registry key/value pair is corrupted.

I found a PowerShell script which fixes the bug and I'm now hosting it on Github at https://github.com/WillBixler/TwinUI-Fix.

Comment: Thanks, Will! I don't have this problem anymore, but for anyone else having it, it's great that there finally is an answer here.